# What kind of type should I use on the Type Library Editor for storing Pointer on x64 platform on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pointers, com, 64-bit, typelib

I need to store `Pointer` on the COM-object on the project for x64 platform on Delphi. What kind of type should I use on the Type Library Editor?

I think we can't use `NativeInt` here and should use `Int64`.

But what is correct `Int64` analog in Type Library Editor then? There is even no [hyper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type on the Type Library Editor!

Comment: [This](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Valid_Types) table may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `__Int64` for that instead `hyper`. Better answer from the comments: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Valid_Types